# Different result of modulo and integer divison for float and Decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am quite confused with the behaviour as shown below:

```
>>> (-7) % 3 
2
>>> Decimal('-7') % Decimal('3') 
Decimal('-1')
>>> 

>>> (-7) // 3
-3
>>> Decimal('-7') // Decimal('3') 
Decimal('-2')
>>>
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Related:  [this bug report.](http://bugs.python.org/issue12005)

Comment: Both are correct, but are based on different definitions of the ambiguous modulus operation when applied to negative numbers - `3*-3+2 == -7`, and `3*-2-1 == -7`. A particular language/library/implementation usually picks one definition, so the fact that native integers and `Decimal` behave differently in this version of Python certainly could be considered a bug - it's at least a surprising inconsistency, as you noted. It's possibly an intentional decision, though, too, but I have no idea what the rationale might be if it is...

Comment: @twalberg: Python's decimal module directly follows the IBM decimal standard, which specifies a remainder operator with the semantics shown.  So when the decimal module was introduced, we had to follow those semantics rather than the already existing ones for the `float` type.  That's the rationale for the difference.  We *could* have chosen not to override `%` at all for Decimal objects, and just make the specified remainder operation available as a method, but it's more convenient to have the `%` spelling available. (Practicality beats purity, and all that.)

Comment: @Makoto: Good find!  I'd completely forgotten about that bug report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [`decimal` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

> There are some small differences between arithmetic on Decimal objects
>   and arithmetic on integers and floats. When the remainder operator *%*
>   is applied to Decimal objects, the sign of the result is the sign of
>   the dividend rather than the sign of the divisor:
>
> ```
> >>> (-7) % 4
> 1
> >>> Decimal(-7) % Decimal(4)
> Decimal('-3')
> ```
>
> The integer division operator *//* behaves analogously, returning the
>   integer part of the true quotient (truncating towards zero) rather
>   than its floor, so as to preserve the usual identity *x == (x // y) * y
>   + x % y*:
>
> ```
> >>> -7 // 4
> -2
> >>> Decimal(-7) // Decimal(4)
> Decimal('-1')
> ```